# Validation to check previous empty input types

Tags: php, jquery

[image]
I am working on multiple input types form where user enter data of 12 months. I need validations on these input types. 
    User need to fill one from sale volume or growth volume and one from sale price and growth price. if user enter value of january month and then did not fill fill value of feb and march. then i need validation when he will try to fill value of april month. Please help me. I had attached the screenshot of input types.

Comment: Have you already tried something with [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) ?

Comment: but you know that client side validation is not secure?

Comment: yes i can check only previous one field. like if user did not enter value for feb month and fill march value. then i can check but if he did not fill feb, march and april values and enter directly may value then what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$('#btn').click(function (){    
  if ($(':text').val().length < 1){
    alert('Fill Values');
  }    
});
```

You can customize code according you need.

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/zqr2Q/1/)

Comment: what are the problem.Can you elaborate ?

Comment: In attached screenshot there are two group of volume and price. Sale volume or growth volume is one group and sale price ,growth price second group. user needs to enter at least one field from both groups.like from first group user need to fill sale volume or growth volume. i want that he will be not able to fill value of next months without filling previous months values.